# A real statistic for pay-per-click advertisement

Tags: probability

After each click happens a "conversion" with probability $p$. All conversions are independent.

Suppose there were $n$ clicks and $m$ conversions. What is the probability that $p>p_0$ for a given number $p_0\in[0;1]$? (in general case and if $m=0$)

Probably I've formulated the question not exactly. Probably it should be re-formulated in the terms of aposteriory probabilities.

Please help to formulate my question exactly and find an answer formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that a-priori $p$ has the same probability of having any value in $[0, 1]$ , so $p \sim \mathcal U[0, 1]$, i.e. the a-priori density of $p$ is $f(p)=1$ in $[0, 1]$.

Now let $f(p \mid C)$ be the a-posteriori density of $p$ after seeing a certain amount of clicks.

We  know that given some $p$, the distribution of the clicks is Binomial, so
$$
\mathbb P(C = m \mid p) = {n\choose m}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}
$$
Now, by a generalized version of Bayes theorem
$$
f(p \mid C) = \frac{\mathbb P(C = m \mid p) f(p)}{\int^1_0 \mathbb P(C = m \mid p)f(p)dp} = \frac{{n\choose m}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}}{\int^1_0 {n\choose m}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}dp}
$$
So if you can evaluate this expression (not sure how to evaluate that integral by hand though), what remains is evaluating
$$
\mathbb P (p > p_0 \mid C)=\int^1_{p_0} f(p \mid C) dp
$$
Or put another way
$$
\mathbb P (p > p_0 \mid C)=\frac{\int^1_{p_0}p^m(1-p)^{n-m}dp}{\int^1_0 p^m(1-p)^{n-m}dp}
$$